# Clear tags when asking question and you change site

Tags: feature-request, android-app, asking-questions

On the Android app when you ask a question you can choose what site to ask the question on and search for tags on that site, however, if you pick some tags and change the site that you are asking the question on the tags stay. If you post the question and the tag doesn't exist then the tag is created (for example one of the tags on this question is from the Sci-fi site and don't exist on this one).

My suggestion is to:

- show some message that since you have changed site the tags you have might not exist and will be created
- or clear the tag list so it is blank.